# Javascript Async Await wait for two functions to complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to get my head around async/await.

I have the following code which calls:

- `submitHandler()` which posts a form's inputs to Google sheets

```
                const scriptURL =
                        'GOOGLE SCRIPT URL'
                const form = document.forms.emailform
                fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })
                        .then(response => {
                                console.log('Success!', response)
                                setFormSuccess(1)
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                                console.error('Error!', error.message)
                                setFormSuccess(2)
                        })
        }
```

- `childRef.current.upload()` which posts a file to S3...

but I need to wait for the results from both these functions before I call another function to open a modal and pass in the results of these two functions.

Can anybody help me please?

Many Thanks

```
async function onSubmit() {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                                submitHandler()
                                childRef.current.upload()
                        }, 1000)
                }
                //I want to wait for onSubmit to complete and then call another function which sets state and then launches a modal
```

EDIT: I for got to mention in the original question that I have tried await in all of the functions I call, but none of them work

Comment: https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing some "await" statements. Also I modified the timeout.

```
async function onSubmit() {
                    let sleep = function (ms) {
                        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
                    }
                    await sleep(1000)
                    await submitHandler()
                    await childRef.current.upload()
            }
            //I want to wait for onSubmit to complete and then call another function which sets state and then launches a modal
```

Also in the submitHandler() you are not correctly using async-await. You are using the .then methods, which cannot be easily combined with the await.

```
    async submitHandler() {
            const scriptURL = 'GOOGLE SCRIPT URL'
            const form = document.forms.emailform
            try {
                let response = await fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })
                console.log('Success!', response)
                setFormSuccess(1)
            } catch(error) {
                console.error('Error!', error.message)
                setFormSuccess(2)
            }
    }
```

If you want to still catch errors, you have to wrap the fetch in a try block.

Comment: Thanks sorry I forgot to mention that the await submitHandler() give an error that await is only allowed in async functions

Comment: I was too fast, I have edited my answer. I hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks @kevin. That comes up up with 'await' has no affect on this type of expression

Comment: on the submitHandler() function. I have added function this to the question now

Comment: This is great thanks so much @kevin. Could you give me a steer on the fetch block for the catch equivalent

Comment: @NickWild I added it to my answer. I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as accepted if it helped :)

Comment: Brililant thanks so much @kevin. Still not sure I grok this but it solves my problem and I will try to read more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await multiple Promises, like so

```
const result = await Promise.all([submitHandler(), childRef.current.upload()]);
```

Comment: Thanks @riwen. Although Kevinkreps answer sorted my problem out I also need this to await the second function too

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return `Promise`. So return your `fetch()`

```
submitHeader(){
      const scriptURL =
                    'GOOGLE SCRIPT URL'
            const form = document.forms.emailform
           return fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })
                    .then(response => {
                            console.log('Success!', response)
                            setFormSuccess(1)
                            return response;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                            console.error('Error!', error.message)
                            setFormSuccess(2)
                    })
    }
```

So at you main function you could

```
async function onSubmit() {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                            const response = await submitHandler()
                            // Your response will be available here
                            console.log(response);
                            childRef.current.upload()
                    }, 1000)
            }
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot to mention that I had tried await on all the functions and none of them worked. I will amend my question now

Comment: but it is important what is your function returning await could be uset only with Promise return.

Comment: The submit handler function posts to a google script with a fetch, then, catch that changes state on then and catche depending on whether the fetch is succesful or not. Sorry to be so dumb on this! :-)

Comment: could you show code snippet please? I is impossible to help you when we do not have real returns of your functions

Comment: Thanks @Filip I have added the code for the submitHandler() to original question. Please let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you need to mark the callback to `setTimeout` as `async` if you want to `await` inside it.

But `setTimeout` uses callbacks and thus deviate from the control flow you desire. Thus I'd use a simple promise wrapper to make it happen :

```
const promiseSetTimeout = (cb, delay) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    const ret = await cb();
    resolve(ret);
  }, delay);
});
```

Thus you can await on it and have the desired control flow.

```
function onSubmit() {
  return promiseSetTimeout(async () => {
    await submitHandler();
    await childRef.current.upload();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vivick I am getting promiseSetTimeout is not defined

Comment: You did copy the implementation I gave you in the same file (or imported it if it's somewhere else)?

Comment: Thanks yes In the same file - I just coped and pasted. It also has an error that await has no effect on this type of expression for the await submitHandler()

Comment: That's probably because it does not return a promise

Comment: Thanks I have amened the question to include the submitHandler(). Any thoughts?

Comment: You should return your call to `fetch` other than that it should work fine. Awaiting on something that is not really awaitable won't be an issue